# PHP isn't getting processed in javascript section of code?

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code in home_view.php:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function updateContent(path, args) {
                $.post(path+args, function( data ) {
                    $( "#content" ).html( data );
                });
            }

            updateContent(<?php echo base_url("/show_cards/load_page")."/"; ?>, <?php echo $set; ?>);
        });

    </script>
```

PHP isn't working here:

```
updateContent(<?php echo base_url("/show_cards/load_page")."/"; ?>, <?php echo $set; ?>);
```

All PHP in the file is being processed minus the part in the javascript section. Why is this?

Comment: Is this in an external js file? What's the file extension and is your server set up to process that extension/mime as php? PHP is not at all 'aware' whether you're running it within a script section of HTML or not.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or anything?

Comment: Your server doesn't proceed this. Are you use something else then .php extension.

Comment: @JAL: The file name is home_view.php all php within the file works minus the javascript part.

Comment: What about the PHP doesn't work? Does the browser get the PHP tags when you view source? (That seems unlikely since you say it works elsewhere in the page).

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question next time - 'not working' makes it sound like the php isn't being processed at all. Turns out, it simply was not producing the intended result. Big difference.

Comment: Also, turned out the problem was in js, not php!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YOu have to enclose the URL with single quotes

```
updateContent('<?php echo base_url("/show_cards/load_page")."/"; ?>', '<?php echo $set; ?>');
```